# DOM and Javascript Object manipulation in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I'm working on a module to save browser memory and stuck at some point. Taking an example, I have a webpage with two frames. Let's say these two frames are exactly the same web page, which means that they should share DOM and Javascript object. However, the current Firefox browser still treat them differently, which means I have duplicate DOM and Javascript Object in my memory. I want to add a feature that they can share DOM and Javascript Object. I tried the approach to modify the Firefox source code but it introduces a lot of new bugs which makes the browser crash again and again. I know there is a DOM inspector which can find all the DOMs, insert new ones, or delete the existing ones. So I want to ask if I can implement this sharing feature using a browser plugin. Or, I would really appreciate it if you can give me some inspiration.

Comment: Why are you using frames then? Frames are meant to sandbox...

Comment: That's what I meant as well. Why are you using iframes?